# Use of bitwise '|' with boolean operands in React Native while building in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native, mobile

[image]

It shows the above error in Xcode

`Update the Yoga package to v1.19.0,`

`Use patch-package for development ease`

`Add postinstall script to package.json file with patch-package call`

`Edit react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp to fix the issue with incorrect operator used Execute npx patch-package react-native to generate .patch file Make sure to add patches/ directory to git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Edit the react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp file to fix the issue with the incorrect operator used. Replace the bitwise '|' operator with the logical '||' operator.
- Yoga.cpp issue with Xcode 14.3 (14E222b) : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36758#issuecomment-1496210081
- Xcode 14.3 Use of bitwise ‘|’ with boolean operands : https://toyboy2.medium.com/xcode-14-3-use-of-bitwise-with-boolean-operands-d4784faf5e73